# Casting complex, non-primitive C++ data types into Erlang/Elixir format, to export methods using NIF

Tags: c++, erlang, elixir, c++17, ffi

I'm writting a library in C++ which I'll use in Elixir/Erlang. There're C++ methods that accept and return, including via out parameters, and involving pointers, data structures or library  from `std` library such as: tuples, vectors, priority queues, bitsets and so forth. And also methods that accept or return generics. Or my own custom data structures.

How do I export such methods?

```
  template<class T1>
  std::array<MyStruc1, 24> my_func(
    const T1& a1,
    int b1,
    int c1,
    unordered_map<MyStruc1, double>& d1,
    unordered_map<MyStruc2, int>* e1=nullptr) {

    ///////
  }
```

I'm familiar with, and have found examples, converting simple structures: char*, simple structs and primitive types only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Erlang, types are what are defined in [here](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html). Internal Erlang and C/C++ std representations do not match, you cannot return a, for example, `int64_t` from C and use it directly from Erlang.

Same for complex structures, is `PrioryQueue` an Erlang's `list()` or a `{list(), pos_integer()}`?

This means that you need to transform types back and forth, using the `enif_get_*` and `enif_make_*` [erl_nif](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html) functions. For really complex structures this may be tedious, so you really need to consider if it wouldn't be enough using [resource objects](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#resource_objects).

Resource objects are just pointers to memory, and thus, opaque for Erlang. You can have this opaque hold the pointer to the priority queue memory and include methods to `put/2` and `get/2` Erlang terms to the queue.

**Why are the functions from [erl_nif](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html) required?**

Erlang has dynamic typing, where each reference held by a variable includes its type (either in the value for the immediate terms, or in the reference for the referenced terms), while C/C++ have static typing, where the variable is the one that states the type only at compile time.

For C/C++, `0xfabada` could be an `int`, `uint`, a `char*`, a `void*` pointing to your custom structure...

Other reasons for the representations not to match include:

1. Erlang's integers have variable size
2. Erlang terms are tagged (some bits of the reference indicate the type)
3. The closest thing to an atom in C/C++ is an enum, and they are quite different
4. Binaries (both short an long binaries) and subbinaries
5. Memory management
   ... and so on.

Comment: regarding direction and the point of all the conversions that the methods `nif_*` --> is it to convert types *from C++* to Erlang or *from Erlang* to C++?

Comment: @pavel You have both directions. With the `enif_make_*` you create Erlang terms from C/C++ types and with the `enif_get_*` you extract C/C++ from the Erlang terms

Comment: The point and direction of functions-wrappers such as `ERL_NIF_TERM my_nif_cpp_func(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[]) {...}` --> from C++ to Erlang or from Erlang to C++?

Comment: Nifs are called from Erlang code and handled by C code, if you want the other way around, you'd need to create a driver instead of nifs. I understand that, since you are developing a library, the behaviour you want is the one provided by nifs.

You can check [this file in the official repo](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/erts/example/matrix_nif.c) or [this json parser](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy) as examples.

Comment: The point and direction of functions-wrappers such as `ERL_NIF_TERM my_nif_cpp_func(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[]) {...}` --> from C++ to Erlang or from Erlang to C++?

Comment: From Erlang to C++

Comment: Not only. Erlang to C++, calculations in C++  and then C++ to Erlang. No?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with "called from Erlang and handled by C code" in my comment above. The nif is executed from Erlang, but eventually it must return the control (and any terms) to it.